# mod rewrite internal error 500 multiple slash

Tags: mod-rewrite, slash

Can someone help me again regarding this rewrite module,

with this rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [QSA,L]
```

with this rules, i can get the requested url
www.example.com/test to www.example.com/test.php
but how can i get following url
www.example.com/test/test2/test3/test4 to www.example.com/test.php

i tried

```
RewriteRule (.*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

don't laugh at me... i actually tried

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

and this works for this link

www.example.com/test/test2/test3/test4 to www.example.com/test.php

but, not for this one...

www.example.com/test to www.example.com/test.php

i'm using explode on Php cause i don't know how many parameters, that i need, if it is only 2 parameters, and this rules should be work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?([^/]*)$ p.php?s=%1&p=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

i did keep checking every similiar questions, which appear on the right, but i don't see any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were creating an endless redirect. Try this checking for `.php` in the request. Also if you're not pulling the slashes the Apache would redirect to a non-existent index.php inside of some folder.

**Example 1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

This takes the first directory matched and pulls it into the query string.

`www.example.com/file/param1/param2/param3` shows this `www.example.com/file.php`

**Example 2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?params=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This takes the first directory matched and pulls it into the query string. The rest of the URI is added as a parameter

`www.example.com/file/param1/param2/param3`
shows this `www.example.com/file.php?params=param1/param2/param3`

**Example 3**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?([^/.]+)?/?([^/.]+)?/?([^/.]+)?$ $1.php?p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4 [QSA,L]
```

`www.example.com/file/param1/param2/param3`
shows this `www.example.com/file.php?p1=param1&p2=param2&p3=param3`

---

Note: `[QSA]` keeps the existing parameters, so `&original_parameter=param` is appended to the rewritten query string.

Comment: thanks for the respone, but as i know, it will redirect all the request to the file test.php, isn't it?
but what i want actually the first value behind the slash for the script file and then the rest will ignored.
for example www.example.com/file/param1/param2/param3
to this www.example.com/file.php

Comment: i tried this website
http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/
it give a results
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ $1.php?params=$2 [L]

for this

www.example.com/file/param1/param2/param3 to this www.example.com/file.php?params=param1/param2/param3

but it doesn't work. any other idea?

Comment: awesome... that is a quick respone, anyway example 2 works for the url www.example.com/file/ and www.example.com/file/params/params, but not for the www.example.com/file and then i looked on your third example, i add a "?" like this.. RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?(.*)$ $1.php?params=$2 [QSA,L]... it's done... great!! thanks a lot.... too bad i can't vote up ur answer....